# I don't know why my JS code for LeetCode Copy List with Random Pointer question is wrong

Tags: javascript, linked-list

This is the leetcode question [138. Copy List with Random Pointer](https://leetcode.com/problems/copy-list-with-random-pointer/)

> A linked list of length n is given such that each node contains an
> additional random pointer, which could point to any node in the list,
> or null.
>
> Construct a deep copy of the list. The deep copy should consist of
> exactly n brand new nodes, where each new node has its value set to
> the value of its corresponding original node. Both the next and random
> pointer of the new nodes should point to new nodes in the copied list
> such that the pointers in the original list and copied list represent
> the same list state. **None of the pointers in the new list should point
> to nodes in the original list**.

Here is my code:

```js
        function Node(val, next, random) {
            this.val = val;
            this.next = next;
            this.random = random;
        };
        var copyRandomList = function (head) {
            const old2NewMap = new Map()

            let pointer = head;
            while (pointer) {
                const tempNewNode = new Node(pointer.val);
                old2NewMap.set(pointer, tempNewNode)
                pointer = pointer.next;
            }

            pointer = head;
            while (pointer) {
                const tempNewNode = old2NewMap.get(pointer);
                tempNewNode.next = old2NewMap.get(pointer.next)
                tempNewNode.random = old2NewMap.get(pointer.random)
                pointer = pointer.next;
            }

            return old2NewMap.get(head)
        };
```

And it can passed on my local PC, at least no error. Here is the test code:

```js
        const th1Node = new Node(7, null, null)
        const th2Node = new Node(13, null, null)
        const th3Node = new Node(11, null, null)
        const th4Node = new Node(10, null, null)
        const th5Node = new Node(1, null, null)

        th1Node.next = th2Node;
        th1Node.random = null;

        th2Node.next = th3Node;
        th2Node.random = th1Node;

        th3Node.next = th4Node;
        th3Node.random = th5Node;

        th4Node.next = th5Node;
        th4Node.random = th3Node;

        th5Node.next = null;
        th5Node.random = th1Node;
    
        console.log(copyRandomList(th1Node))
```

However, when I submit it tell me wrong:

```
Line 83 in solution.js
            node = node.next;
                        ^
TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'next')
    Line 83: Char 25 in solution.js (Object.serializer.isCyclic)
    Line 109: Char 24 in solution.js (Object.serializer.serializeLinkedList)
    Line 165: Char 30 in solution.js (Object.<anonymous>)
    Line 16: Char 8 in runner.js (Object.runner)
    Line 28: Char 26 in solution.js (Object.<anonymous>)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1101:14)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1153:10)
    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:981:32)
    at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:822:12)
    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (node:internal/modules/run_main:81:12)
```

I don't know why

Comment: The error message indicates that there is an issue with trying to access the next property of an undefined variable in the code. Maybe the node variable is not being initialized or defined correctly in the code. I do not know which line is line number 83 in this code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`node.next` is supposed to be `null` for the last node in the list. But when you do:

```
tempNewNode.next = old2NewMap.get(pointer.next)
```

`pointer.next` is `null`, and there's no entry in `old2NewMap` for this value. `get()` returns `undefined`, not `null`. You need to convert that to `null`.

```
tempNewNode.next = old2NewMap.get(pointer.next) || nulll
```